# Enable https for java ejb Webservice

Tags: web-services, netbeans, https, ejb

i'm developing a webservice with ejb 3 and glassfish 3.1.1. I'm using Netbeans 7.0 and would like to know, how to enable https on port 8181 for this webservice.

I dont need any authentication method, just secure the communication through https!

Thx

Adem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify a secure connection as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html#bncbm). Essentially, in your deployment descriptor web.xml you need to set:

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However `NetBeans` will insert the code for you: open `web.xml`, click the Security tab along the top of the editor, then click the Add Security Constraint button. Type a name, in URL pattern write /*, set All Http Methods, and specify `Confidential` as Transport Guarantee.

If you don't have `web.xml`, because you are deploying just the Enterprise Java Bean, create a New GlassFish Descriptor `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` and fill it like this (or see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giida.html#scrolltoc) the file hierarchy):

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
      <ejb-name>Hello</ejb-name>
      <webservice-endpoint>
        <port-component-name>Hello</port-component-name>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </webservice-endpoint>
    </ejb>  
  </enterprise-beans>/>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

Your application will use port 8181 from now on.

See [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/security.html) for further information about how to setup security in a Netbeans web application and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html) for learning about certificates.

Comment: Are you sure that this solution also works on ejb webservices. I can imagine that this would be applicable when using webservice over servlets, but how about ejb webservice.

Is it possible to set the transport guarantee for ejb webservices in a descriptor file, perhaps `sun-ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: @AdemC I am happy for that. Accept the answer if it was useful, in order to increase your reputation and get more rights in StackOverflow

Comment: Only creating the glassfish specific descriptor file (glassfish-ejb-jar.xml) with your suggested content above helped to solve the situation if the web service implemented in EJB with @WebService annotation. The security constraint section in web.xml did nothing in this case.