# Java Web Service in Glassfish with https

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, https

I'm trying to deploy a web service in Glassfish 3.1 which works with http and https. It works fine in http but when trying in https it says

> Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL
>   https://****.***:8181/UserWebService/UserWebService?WSDL
>
> Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not
>   configured for security

The server log says:

> Invalid request scheme for Endpoint UserWebService. Expected http . Received https
>
> Failed to parse metadata returned from server at ....
>
> [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
>
> Failed to parse the WSDL.

As I said, it works perfectly through http but it fails with https.

What is wrong? Should I change anything in my NetBeans project?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your server configured to support SSL?

Comment: Yes, I followed this tutorial: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/ and when opening the index page it shows the "lock" correctly.

Comment: Is your WSDL accessible over https ? Also do the service URL contains https ?

Comment: I think it's not accssible, Santosh, it returns a "blank" page. How can I make it accessible?

Comment: You can find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882056/enable-https-for-java-ejb-webservice

Answer (score 0):

My problem was proxy/antivirus problem I finally download the wsdl file and copy that in the  project folder and type following command

`wsimport -p com.yourdomain.package -s src -d bin downloaded_wsdl_file.xml`

Then it generated all java files in your src folder and all .class files in bin directory