# (Java) Web services can't be accessable due to https

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy and use a web service, using EJB and Glassfish server.
I'd like to test a web service and use a wsdl of this, which is deployed by Glassfish.
However, this produces an error message on its tester, saying

```
Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL https://xxxx:8181/yyyy/zzzz?WSDL

Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security
```

I serched for a solution in stack overflow, and this seems to be the one.
([Enable https for java ejb Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882056/enable-https-for-java-ejb-webservice)).

According to this posting, I need to have "web.xml" or "glassfish-ejb-jar.xml".
(If the former is missing, the latter needs to be created.)

However, there is no file named "web.xml" in my EJB.
Also, although there are a lot of information on the internet about what "glassfish-ejb-jar.xml" is, I cannot find how to create it.

Could anyone please give information about how to create it, or an alternataive way to deal with this error?

***EDIT***

*I'm going to call this EJB "A" from here.

*Before I created "A", I created another EJB named "B". "B" is already deployed by Glassfish.

*B's tester of https is not accessible, but its http tester and WSDl are accesible.
(i.e. At least B can be viewed and produce its WSDL)

*"A" is using B's methods, by creating a web service client and using B's WSDl for this client.

*I confirmed that B's mathods can be used by other classes, by using its WSDL inside a web client.

- Both A nad B are created by Netbenas, and i didin't use any other tool.

Comment: Is access using HTTP no option? -> http://xxxx:8181/yyyy/zzzz?WSDL otherwise beside activating SSL serverside your client will have to add the servers certificate to its local truststore.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
HTTP is another option, but when I try to test it, there appears (almost) the same message.
"Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL http://xxx:8080/yyy/zzz?WSDL"
"Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security"

Comment: Sorry i had a bit of a missunderstanding (currently tracking 5 webservice issues at work;)) so may i ask if you are able to access/view/open your WSDL by entering the HTTP/S URLs into a Webbrowser? (That way we know if its even worth to proceed with the code generation tools like wsimport). Also: What tool is used to generate the stubs from the WSDL?

Comment: I cannot access the WSDL by web browser either. When I put the WSDL url into webbrowser, there appears a message, "Invalid wsdl request http://xxx:8080/yyy/zzz".

Comment: Tool...I didn't use any tool other than Netbeans and Glassfish. I made an EJB and web service class. Next, I used WSDls of other web service classes, imported the methods of the imported classes into the newly created EJB, and then deployed the EJB by Glassfish. I hope this explanation is clear.

Comment: WSDL not available in Browser: Arg unfortunately that could have a lot of reasons including the one your webservice was not deployed successfully. Can you check the status of your deployment on a Glassfish Webinterface or something like that (i only know Websphere)

Comment: Tools: I thought you are trying to "play the consumer" by generating classes out of your WSDL hosted remote using a tool like wsimport. But that part doesnt matter that much anymore since you cant access it as a browser.

Comment: I recomend you enrich your question with a couple more details about what exactly you are doing (becaue the part "I made an EJB and webservice class. Next, I used SWDIs of other webservice classes.." and the part where you dont have a web.xml confuses me a little bit ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I modified my queston. Hope this is clearer.